# Ploting dataframe with NAs with linearly joined points

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a dataframe where each column has many missing values. How can I make a plot where the datapoints in each column are joined with lines, i.e. NAs are ignored, instead of having a choppy plot?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

d = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.choice([np.nan] + list(range(7)), size=(10,3)))
d.plot(markers=True)
```

One way is to use this for each column:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name="linear",
                    line_shape='linear'))
```

Are there any better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **pandas** [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html).  Have demonstrated using **plotly express** and chained use so underlying data is not changed.

Post comments have amended answer so that markers are not shown for interpreted points.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.choice([np.nan] + list(range(7)), size=(10, 3)))
px.line(d).update_traces(mode="lines+markers").add_traces(
    px.line(d.interpolate(limit_direction="both")).update_traces(showlegend=False).data
)
```

[image]

Comment: But this would add points on the plot which I don't want to.

Comment: think we're defining things differently.  no points have been added as dataframe is unchanged.  For purpose of plotting as per your statement, have interpolated NaN rather than having a break in the line....

Comment: I understand that the dataframe is unchanged, but new interpolated filled circles appeared on the plot instead of a solid line with no filled circles on the missing positions.

Comment: ok - have updated so that interpolated points will not show a marker